# android simplexml parse elements with dynamic name

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic, simple-framework

I need some advice how to parse this xml with java simplexml lib.
Problem is that i don't how how many items i will have in this xml element.

```
<Playoffs>
<PlayoffStatus>Potential Brackets</PlayoffStatus>
<LConference>Western Conference</LConference>
<RConference>Eastern Conference</RConference>
<LTeam1>Clippers (1)</LTeam1>
<LTeam2>Nuggets (8)</LTeam2>
<LTeam3>Grizzlies (4)</LTeam3>
<LTeam4>Warriors (5)</LTeam4>
<LTeam5>Spurs (3)</LTeam5>
<RTeam1>Heat (1)</RTeam1>
<RTeam2>Celtics (8)</RTeam2>
<RTeam3>Pacers (4)</RTeam3>
<RTeam4>Bulls (5)</RTeam4>
<RTeam5>Hawks (3)</RTeam5>
    .......
```

Comment: try SAXParser that will help you sure...

Comment: What did you try? What problem are you having?

Comment: IMHO the way you're structuring your XML is wrong. The nodes you've chosen are wrong, the structure is wrong.. If you want to structure your data, I suggest you doing so: `<Playoffs><PlayoffStatus>Potential Brackets</PlayoffStatus><Conference id="Western Conference"><Team id="1">Clippers</Team>
<Team id="8">Nuggets</Team>
<Team id="4">Grizzlies</Team>...</Conference>...</PlayOffs>` and so on

Comment: in all project i use simplexml  lib http://simple.sourceforge.net/ and for all elements I use annotation  in model class like this: @Element(name = "PlayoffStatus", required = false)
    private String playoffStatus; how can i do this with dynamic named elements

Comment: @m0skit0 i agree with you . But i want resolve this problem without server side guys and i want to save my time

Comment: Who talked about server side? You don't need a server for anything, my friend. The way you have your XML now is gonna be a headache to parse, whatever parser you use, and you will not save any time, trust me. You should change your XML structure. For example, having <LTeam1> is completely useless, because then you will need to parse <LTeam1> separate from <LTeam2> because it's 2 different nodes when you can use the same node <Team>. I suggest you read about XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Converter object or the @ElementListUnion interface. See here for an example.

https://simple.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/simple/trunk/download/stream/src/test/java/org/simpleframework/xml/core/UnionInlineListWitinPathTest.java

https://simple.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/simple/trunk/download/stream/src/test/java/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/HideEnclosingConverterTest.java